# Removing accents from Times New Roman in small-caps

Tags: xetex, accents, greek, small-caps

I just joined the extremely helpful community!

I'm writing my thesis using LaTeX and I have modified how chapters are shown. I want to have my chapters in small caps but the chapters in order to look beautiful have to be written without accents and in toc appeared with no accents either but in toc the font is normal (no small-caps). In all capital form like in Title there is no such problem. Also I have a similar problem with list of tables and figures. I can't change their names in order not to appear the accents.

So my question is: "Is there any way to force times new roman to show the accents when I'm writing in small-caps?"

Here's my MWE

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                    Thesis Template                        %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,titlepage]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry,tabu}
\usepackage{titlesec}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Document Informatio%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \title{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{Τίτλος}}}

 \author{Joe Doe}

 \date{\today}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Περιεχομενα} %I used it to remove the accents from toc
 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
 \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\normalsize \bfseries \huge  }%
{\normalsize \flushright %
\centering\MakeUppercase{\partname}\hspace{1ex}%
{\thepart}}%
{15 pt  }%
{\centering\MakeUppercase{\expandafter{\bfseries\Huge}}}[\vspace{-45 pt}\titlerule]%  %Unfortunately I can't force the part be in Caps

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalsize \bfseries \Huge  }%
{\flushright\normalsize %
\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\hspace{1ex}%
{\Huge\thechapter}}%
{15 pt \titlerule }%
{\scshape \Huge }[\vspace{15 pt}\titlerule]%

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\normalsize  \huge  }%
{\flushright\normalsize}%
{15 pt }%
{\scshape\bfseries \Huge }[\titlerule]%

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
{\bfseries\normalsize }{\Large\thesection}{5pt}{\bfseries \Large}

\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]
{\bfseries\normalsize }{\Large\thesubsection}{5pt}{\bfseries \Large}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]
{\bfseries\normalsize }{\large\thesubsubsection}{5pt}{\bfseries \large}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\scshape\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}


\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\roman{subsubsection}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\frontmatter


\maketitle




\tableofcontents
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Καταλογος Πινακων} %I have written it without the accents but when I compile the code I get it with the accents
\listoftables
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Καταλογος Σχηματων} %same here
\listoffigures
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\mainmatter
\newgeometry{left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm}


\part{Θεωρία}
\chapter[Εισαγωγή]{Εισαγωγη} % I use that syntax in order to fix the problem but it works only in chapters, sections, etc. 
\lipsum
\section{Ενότητα}
\lipsum

\subsection{Υποενότητα}
\lipsum[10]



\begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
    \label{pinaks1}
    \caption{Πιναξ 111}
    \begin{tabu}{X[j] X[l] X[c] X[r]}
        \hline
    Justified & Left    & Center & Right \\
        \hline \hline
        & & & \\
        \hline
    \end{tabu}
\end{table}

\subsubsection{Ύπο-υποενότητα}
\lipsum[3]



\paragraph{Παράγραφος}
\lipsum[3]

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \caption{Blah\ldots}
\end{figure}

\subparagraph{Υποπαράγραφος}
\lipsum


\backmatter
\appendix

\end{document}
```

I hope I was informative enough about my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interesting question but this might be a very difficult task.  The problem is that Greek in Unicode is a complete mess and, e.g. ['GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA WITH DASIA' (U+1F01)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f01/index.htm) ἁ is an own character rather than ['GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA' (U+03B1)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03b1/index.htm) α and a combining dasia (which does not exist).

Comment: Of course, the Unicode consortium is focusing on the issue at hand and adopted [new important characters](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-released.html) such as, [elf](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-released.html#1f9dd) with a palette of combining skin colours. 

Comment: I have to find another workaround like `\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{whatever}` or similar.
Thanks for the input anyway @HenriMenke